# Deezer Javascript SDK on localhost

Tags: javascript, localhost, deezer

For developing I would like to use the Deezer Javascript SDK on localhost. I set the application domain on `localhost:8000`, but it didn't work. My HTML file is on `localhost:8000`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Deezer to Spotify</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dz-root"></div>
<script src="http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js"></script>
<script src="DeezerToSpotifySwitcher.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My javascript file:

```
DZ.init({
  appId: '147671',
  channelUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/DeezerToSpotifySwitcher.html'
});

DZ.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        DZ.api('/user/me', function (response) {
            alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
    } else {
        alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
}, { perms: 'basic_access,email' });
```

What application domain do I have to set? Did I miss something else?

Comment: Did you try to update your application domain in developers.deezer.com to localhost:8000? It should work.

Comment: yes, I did, but didn't help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, using domain *deezer-dl.local:8888*.

On https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php, it was displaying:

> ```
>   You must enter a valid redirect uri
> ```

I solved the problem by fixing the Application Domain in Deezer applications' preferences to *deezer-dl.local* (without port) and using the standard 80 port for my application...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with : channelUrl: 'http://yourAppDomain.com/channel.php'

or

channelUrl: 'http://yourAppDomain.com/channel.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it only works without explicit port definition - so just reconfigure your local server to run on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Try `127.0.0.1:8000` instead of `localhost:8000`. And don't forget to add it to permitted hosts as `127.0.0.0.1:8000`. And you don't have to use 80 port in this case.

Worked perfectly for me.